# OpenSSL Config error when generating self-signed certificate string too long

Tags: openssl

With the following OpenSSL Config

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_md          = sha256
default_keyfile     = drone-ci-web.company.com.key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_ext
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only
prompt              = no
encrypt_key         = no

[ subject ]
countryName                    = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default            = US
stateOrProvinceName            = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default    = Missouri
localityName                   = Locality Name (eg, city)
localityName_default           = Jefferson City
organizationName               = Organization Name (eg, company)
organizationName_default       = My Company
organizationalUnitName         = Organizational Unit (eg, team)
organizationalUnitName_default = My Company Technologies
commonName                     = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_default             = drone-ci-web.company.com
emailAddress                   = Email Address
emailAddress_default           = DL_EMAIL_LIST@company.com

[ x509_ext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
basicConstraints       = CA:FALSE
keyUsage               = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName         = @alternate_names
nsComment              = "Drone-CI - OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ req_ext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
basicConstraints     = CA:FALSE
keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName       = @alternate_names
nsComment            = "Drone-CI - OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ alternate_names ]
DNS.1 = drone-ci-web.company.com
```

I run the following command:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -config drone-ssl.cnf -new -out drone-ci-web.company.com.cert.pem
```

and I get the following error:

```
vagrant@jonspc ~]$ sudo openssl req -x509 -config drone-ssl.cnf -new -out drone-ci-web.ccompany.com.cert.pem
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
..............................................................................................................+++
....................+++
writing new private key to 'drone-ci-web.company.com.key.pem'
-----
problems making Certificate Request
140184216713104:error:0D07A097:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_mbstring_ncopy:string too long:a_mbstr.c:158:maxsize=2
```

From what I think its telling me, one of the fields its trying to use is "Too long" and is only two characters, but from what I keep reading, the `countryName_default` should override the `countryName` and make this accept the value given for default.

OpenSSL and Operating System information:

```
[vagrant@jonspc ~]$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
[vagrant@jonspc ~]$ cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 7.5
[vagrant@jonspc ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
```

HOWEVER, if I remove the `_default` lines and try again, this succeeds with the following config.

```
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_md          = sha256
default_keyfile     = drone-ci-web.company.com.key.pem
distinguished_name  = subject
req_extensions      = req_ext
x509_extensions     = x509_ext
string_mask         = utf8only
prompt              = no
encrypt_key         = no

[ subject ]
countryName            = US
stateOrProvinceName    = Missouri
localityName           = Jefferson City
organizationName       = My Company
organizationalUnitName = My Company Technologies
commonName             = drone-ci-web.company.com
emailAddress           = DL_EMAIL_LIST@company.com

[ x509_ext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier   = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid,issuer
basicConstraints       = CA:FALSE
keyUsage               = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName         = @alternate_names
nsComment              = "Drone-CI - OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ req_ext ]
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
basicConstraints     = CA:FALSE
keyUsage             = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName       = @alternate_names
nsComment            = "Drone-CI - OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

[ alternate_names ]
DNS.1 = drone-ci-web.company.com
```

This works with the following output.

```
[vagrant@jonspc ~]$ sudo openssl req -x509 -config drone-ssl.cnf -new -out drone-ci-web.company.com.cert.pem
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
..............+++
..............+++
writing new private key to 'drone-ci-web.company.com.key.pem'
-----
```

Comment: [How to create a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/req.html):

> DISTINGUISHED NAME AND ATTRIBUTE SECTION FORMAT There are two separate
>   formats for the distinguished name and attribute sections. If the
>   prompt option is set to no then these sections just consist of field
>   names and values: for example,

```
 CN=My Name
 OU=My Organization
 emailAddress=someone@somewhere.org
```

> This allows external programs (e.g. GUI based) to generate a template
>   file with all the field names and values and just pass it to req. An
>   example of this kind of configuration file is contained in the
>   EXAMPLES section. Alternatively if the prompt option is absent or not
>   set to no then the file contains field prompting information. It
>   consists of lines of the form:

```
 fieldName="prompt"
 fieldName_default="default field value"
 fieldName_min= 2
 fieldName_max= 4
```

So basically what you figured out yourself.

Comment: Thank you for pointing all this out! It makes so much more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

It's a field with a two letter constraint. In my case, USA needed to be US.

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer. It's right in my case. You guys can take a look on this site

https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-certificate-country-codes.htm